# Simplifying a Regex expression used to find highlighted words with HTML tags

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Could you explain to me the following regex expression? Why does it have to be so complicated, all it has to do is check if the `em` tag is presented in a text, e.g. `<em>text</em>`, `<pre>whatever</pre>` or something like that, basically highlighted words. https://regex101.com/ pretty much explains what it does in detail.

Can it be simplified?

```cs
[Fact]
public async Task Handle_ShouldReturnHighlightedDescriptions_WhenGivenEmptyInput()
{
    // Arrange
    var query = new GetProductsQuery();

    // Act
    var actual = await _queryHandler.Handle(query, default);

    // Assert
    actual.Products.Should().AllSatisfy(p =>
        p.Description.Should().NotMatchRegex(@"<\s*([^ >]+)[^>]*>.*?<\s*/\s*\1\s*>"));
}
```

Comment: HTML is notoriously hard to parse, it's why it is almost never recommended to use regex for HTML. Instead use a dedicated library like HTML Agility Pack

Comment: @DavidG, what would the alternative for finding highlighted words be using HTML Agility Pack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what the purpose is, but parsing HTML quickly becomes complicated.

If you only want to check whether an HTML string contains *any* tags, then just check for the pattern "`<\w`". But if the HTML also might contain comments (and CData sections), then you have to eliminate false positives like `<!-- <em> -->`, which is possible but requires a significantly more complex pattern.

But the pattern in your example seems like it is not only intended to detect tags, but also to extract the whole element from start to end tag. Unfortunately, this is even more complicated since the pattern does not take into consideration nested elements like `<em>..<em>..</em>..</em>`. If you need to support this you cannot do it with a regex alone, since regexes does not support matching recursive patterns.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! How can I do that, even if it's not regex?

Comment: @nop: Depends what you want to achieve. But the simplest is to use an existing HTML parser. For example the DOM has the method `getElementsByTagName()` which can be used to extract all `em` elements or whatever you want.